# Is there a way in fvwm config to listen for non-standard keyboard buttons?

Tags: configuration, fvwm

What I'm looking to do is modify ~/.fvwm/config, adding a few lines that would allow me adjust the audio volume by hitting non-standard keys on my keyboard (volume adjustment buttons).  I can't see how to detect it though.

Is there any way in FVWM to detect when volume and mute buttons are pressed on a keyboard?

I'm using Kubuntu, and would be happily using KDE if it wasn't continuously crashing (presumably an issue with the video card).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to identify the media keys in question so you can tell fvwm to bind them.  I suggest using xev(1) for this.  Then you'll need to use an appropriate tool to change the volume.  Here's an example:

Key XF86VolUp A A Exec exec volume_increase +5

Here. "XF86VolUp" is the name of the key which xev told me about, and "volume_increase" is some fictional program which might raise the volume.

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I needed.  I'm getting XF86AudioRaiseVolume but close enough.